# How to stop the repetition of code when parsing files

Tags: html, go

I am repeating the same code of html files in every function. I just changed the name of one file in every function and that is `ui/html/home.html` in `indexHandler()` and `ui/html/signup.html` in `signup()`

Other file names are the same and the code of `ParseFiles()` is also the same in each function. How to prevent the code from repeating every time.

```
func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.URL.Path != "/" {
        http.NotFound(w, r)
        return
    }

    files := []string{"ui/html/home.html", "ui/html/footer.html", "ui/html/base.html",}    
    tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles(files...)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    tmpl.Execute(w, nil)
}

func signup(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    files := []string{"ui/html/signup.html", "ui/html/footer.html", "ui/html/base.html",}
    tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles(files...)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    tmpl.Execute(w, nil)
}    

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/signup", signup)
    log.Println("Starting the server at :4000")
    http.ListenAndServe(":4000", nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it a package variable.

https://play.golang.org/p/haDmat_kzkg

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var (
    files = []string{"ui/html/home.html", "ui/html/footer.html", "ui/html/base.html"}
)

func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.URL.Path != "/" {
        http.NotFound(w, r)
        return
    }

    tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles(files...)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    tmpl.Execute(w, nil)
}

func signup(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles(files...)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    tmpl.Execute(w, nil)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/signup", signup)
    log.Println("Starting the server at :4000")
    http.ListenAndServe(":4000", nil)
}
```

If you need to add a template for a specific handler, create a new slice out of the global variable and append to it.

```golang
tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles(append(files,[]string{"..."})...)
```

I think you have to read a bit about effective go in general, https://golang.org/doc/effective_go#initialization
or the go tour https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1

A tip to apply is to compile the template during initialization, rather during the request processing. This will speed up your program.

```golang
package main 

//...

var (
    indexTpml = template.Must(template.ParseFiles(files...))
)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/TgjZYCul9M6

Using some helper functions, one can write,

```golang
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func makeTpl(base string) *template.Template {
    files := []string{base, "ui/html/footer.html", "ui/html/base.html"}
    return template.Must(template.ParseFiles(files...))
}

var (
    indexTpml  = makeTpl("ui/html/home.html")
    signupTpml = makeTpl("ui/html/signup.html")
)

func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.URL.Path != "/" {
        http.NotFound(w, r)
        return
    }
    indexTpml.Execute(w, nil)
}

func signup(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    signupTpml.Execute(w, nil)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/signup", signup)
    log.Println("Starting the server at :4000")
    http.ListenAndServe(":4000", nil)
}
```

Comment: You didn't wrote `ui/html/signup.html` files variable. Every function has different files.

Comment: i have added a section for custom templates per handler.

Comment: Will I have to write multiple variables for multiple. Like you made these two global variables just for indexHandler() function. It was not for signup() function

Comment: @leadershipmanage sorry i did not understand, can you try to explain to me again ?

Comment: @leadershipmanage the other way around is to declare one huge template containing all layouts. But then within your handler you will have to write something like `Tpml.ExecuteTemplate(w, "layout name here <----", nil)`

Comment: @leadershipmanage dnt frget to check for errors in `signupTpml.Execute(w, nil)`, it might be good to know when execution failed!

Comment: Yes I added the err variable to check for errors. Thank you! Can you give me details about ` Tpml.ExecuteTemplate(w, "layout name here <----", nil)` that you mentioned above, although the whole code is in `main.go`. If I need to move that to `handler.go`

Comment: yu can move the code into another file or package without problem, just think that need to `go run .`. I can demonstrate executeTemplate but i know upfront it means, in your case, to go through all templates to encapsulate each of them into a `{{define}} {{/define}}` directive (additional work)

Comment: @leadershipmanage meanwhile you can go through this https://medium.com/@IndianGuru/understanding-go-s-template-package-c5307758fab0 at the end they demonstrates named template execution.